# query works only in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My query works fine when I run it through phpmyadmin. But if I execute a query through php, then it often either returns an empty result or is not correct. Mostly correct, but some values are not correct.

```
$o = 367;
    $sql = "SELECT status FROM sbgf_pl_invoices WHERE CONCAT(',', order_id, ',') LIKE '%,".$o.",%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "status: " . $row["status"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

For example, if the order_id is 250, then I get 1. But it must be 0.

Comment: you just had something different pluggin in here. you were using wpdb->prepare. huge difference from what you have here. You have to factor that prepare escapes with single quotes. you'll need to prepare the statement with machine tags, like {{{%s}}} then replace the '{{{ with '% - remember, % is the wildcard for prepare, and just plain escaping them caused issues I cannot recall at the moment

Comment: Your query is fatally flawed: `CONCAT` will _NOT_ put a comma after the LAST order ID, whereas your `LIKE` _DOES_ put a comma after _every_ order ID.  Instead, why not use the [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator.

Comment: voting to close due to lack of [sql mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)